# Verificar objeto vacio

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 <div ng-if="personas.hijos">
    Tiene hijos
 </div>

 <div ng-if="!personas.hijos">
    No tiene hijos
 </div>

 {{personas.hijos}}  => 

1 - si tiene me devuelve el json
{"test":{"a":0.8625,"b":0.5},"test2":{"a":0.72,"b":0.5}} 

2 - si no tiene me pinta {}
```

El problema es que siempre entra por el primer div, q tiene hijos

Comment: hijos tendria que ser un array !! puedes poner lo que tiene el json que se devuelve?

Comment: acabo de editar para que veas que devuelvo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a añadir una funcion en el controller:

```
$scope.isObjectEmpty = function(obj) {
  return !!Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

y luego llamarla en la vista:

```
 <div ng-if="isObjectEmpty(personas.hijos)">
    Tiene hijos
 </div>

 <div ng-if="!isObjectEmpty(personas.hijos)">
    No tiene hijos
 </div>
```

Siempre entrara en la primera vista porque aunque, tenga o no tenga datos `personas.hijos` es una objeto, y si conviertes un objeto a booleano sera `true`:

```
if ({}) {
  console.log('siempre entrare');
}
```